# Unable to upgrade through sudo apt-get upgrade or through Software Center

Tags: apt, upgrade, software-center, dpkg

I have tried upgrading the software through Software Center however the software center keeps on crashing. When i tried through the terminal I got the following message:-

```
sudo apt-get upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages will be upgraded:
  gir1.2-javascriptcoregtk-3.0 gir1.2-webkit-3.0 gnome-control-center
  gnome-control-center-data libgnome-control-center1
  libjavascriptcoregtk-1.0-0 libjavascriptcoregtk-3.0-0 libssl1.0.0
  libssl1.0.0:i386 libwebkitgtk-1.0-0 libwebkitgtk-1.0-common
  libwebkitgtk-3.0-0 libwebkitgtk-3.0-common openssl xserver-common
  xserver-xorg-core
16 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B/27.4 MB of archives.
After this operation, 17.4 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]? y
Preconfiguring packages ...
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'libclone-perl' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'libc-bin' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'libcogl12:amd64' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'libbz2-1.0:amd64' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'libclutter-gst-2.0-0:amd64' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'libcogl-pango12:amd64' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'libclutter-1.0-common' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'libclucene-core1:amd64' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'libcogl-common' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'libclucene-contribs1:amd64' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'libc-dev-bin' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'libcolamd2.7.1' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'libcloog-isl4:amd64' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'libcmis-0.3-3' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'libclutter-gtk-1.0-0:amd64' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'libclutter-1.0-0:amd64' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: unrecoverable fatal error, aborting:
 files list for package 'libc6-dbg:amd64' is not a regular file
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (2)
```

I have also tried `sudo apt-get -f upgrade` and `sudo apt-get install --reinstall libc6-dbg:amd64` but still got the same error and also tried the `sudo apt-get install -f` and `sudo apt-get autoremove`. It gave the following message.

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 16 not upgraded.
```

Comment: Try `sudo apt-get install -f`

Comment: Nope. It is still not working.. `Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 16 not upgraded.`

Comment: try `sudo apt-get autoremove`

Comment: Tried that too... gave the same message as the above one. `Reading package lists... Done Building dependency tree Reading state information... Done 0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 16 not upgraded.`

Answer (score 0):

Try to reinstall `libc6-dbg:amd64` by running the below command,

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall libc6-dbg:amd64
```

Then run upgrade command,

```
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

Comment: it gave a long list of errors same as above... i am posting it above.. `E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (2)`

Comment: let us discuss here http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11833/room-for-avinash-raj-and-whoever-wants-to-make-company

Answer (score 0):

Try this two options:

```
sudo apt-get check
sudo build-dep
sudo apt-get update
```

or delete that package and run update command again:

```
sudo apt-get purge libc6-dbg:amd64
sudo apt-get update
```

Comment: that also did't work either.. had to use "windows" method finally. Reinstalled ubuntu again.

Comment: It is not good habit my friend to solve a problem in that way. If you want to learn the linux/unix architecture and become a power user of it try to solve all of the problem without reinstall. Because every problem has a solution and it is not right one :)

Comment: I understand and I completely agree with you. I myself dislike to follow that method. However would like to thank everyone for the support.